# Angular Routing - Let the Controller decide which view to present

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I'm struggling to understand how to use `ngroute` in my use case and I'm thinking that I must be approaching it from the wrong direction.

The use-case is as follows

- user enters an identifier in a web page
- an Angular controller responds to an `ng-click` event and makes a server side call passing the identifier
- if the identifier is known to the server side code, a view is displayed which shows details associated with the identifier
- if the identifier is **not** known to the server side code, a different view is displayed, allowing the customer the opportunity to add their details.

I have a service that uses `$resource` to execute the server side call and, depending upon whether or not the identifier is known to the system, I set `$location.path`.

Given this, I am now displaying the current views in the correct circumstance.

*But ....*

When I successfully retrieve the data from the server the view is rendered, but it does not contain any of the data that I have just retrieved. The two views have different controllers - I am assuming that the two controllers have different `$scopes` and that is the reason why the view is not being populated correctly. Is that a correct assumption?

If it is, how do I share the results retrieved in one controller with the processing that takes place in a view associated with a different controller. I thought of either caching it in the service itself and sharing the service, or pushing it into the `$rootscope`, but both of these feel hacky and make me feel that I am taking the wrong approach completely.

What is the normal way of dealing with this sort of use-case?

Comment: The normal way is to load the state from the server. The user must be able to reload the page and have the page displayed correctly. That won't happen if the app expects to find the data in a service because the user is supposed to have reached that page by going through a different page before.

Comment: @JBNizet - I agree, but at the moment I seem to need to load the state twice. Once to find out which page to render and once to make the data appear on the view once it has been rendered. That can't be right surely?

Comment: I would assume that the ID is known by the server and go to the "show details" page. This page would load the details, and get an error from the server (since the ID is unknown. The "show details" page would react to this error by going to the "enter details" page.

Comment: Never thought of that ... I'll give it a try in the morning - thanks very much